# Change tag name in XML using Python

Tags: python, xml, tags

Very new to XML and Python. I want to change the tag names of certain elements in an XML document. Here's how the document looks now:

```
<Company>
  <Employee>
        <SSN>xxxxx1234</SSN>
     <Dependent>
        <SSN>xxxxx4321</SSN>
```

I want to change the `<SSN>` tag under the Employee to `<EE SSN>` and leave the tag under the Dependent the same. The document includes hundreds of companies and thousands of employees both with tens to hundreds of sub elements, so a find and replace option is what I believe I need.

I want to use ElementTree module, but open to other suggestions. There are other modifications I want to make (copying and pasting elements) and will be posting another question, so I would like to maintain one module for all. The only code I have that is working is the importing the data and writing it to a new file. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: “EE SSN” isn’t a valid element name. Could you use something like “EE-SSN”, “EE_SSN”, or “EESSN”?

Answer (score 0):

[ElementTree](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) is your way to go.

First you get the root, and after that it's just a matter of accessing the nodes:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

root = ET.fromstring(xml) # assuming you can store your data in a string (xml)

root[i] # access the ith node of the root
root[i][j] # access the jth node of the ith node
```

To get data from the nodes, you can use:

```
root[i][j].text
```

...where you can change the data as needed.

Comment: Thank you Vinicius! I am having difficulty importing using ET.fromstring. Here is what I have for ET.parse tree = ET.parse('R:/Justin Duell/XML Testing/Benesolv Test.xml'). How does that change with ET.fromstring?

Comment: Getting this error

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#22>", line 1, in <module>
    root = ET.fromstring('R:/Justin Duell/XML Testing/Benesolv Test.xml')
  File "C:\Users\admwrier\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1315, in XML
    parser.feed(text)
  File "<string>", line None
xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 1, column 2

Comment: If you are reading from the disk, you can use `tree = ET.parse(path)` and then get the root using `root = tree.getroot()`, as seen in the documentation.